# integrate the square of angular distance from the node of a spherical triangle

Tags: integration, geometry, trigonometry

Guessab, Noouisser, and Schmeisser "A Definiteness Theory for Cubature Formulae of Order Two",  Constructive Approximation (2006)24:263-288

Define a quantity $R[||\cdot||^2]$ which is $$\sum_{i=1}^N \int_{\Omega_i} ||\underline{x}-\underline{x_i}||^2\,dx$$
where $\Omega_i$ is the Voronoi cell of node/sample-point $\underline{x_i}$ (and there are N points).

I would like to calculate $R[||\cdot||^2]$ for a sample design embedded on the surface of a sphere.  Calculating the Voronoi vertices and from them the area of the fractional spherical triangles making up the Voronoi cell is complicated but already solved. Calculating

But I'm having trouble doing $$\int_{\omega_{i,j}} ||\underline{x}-\underline{x_i}||^2dx$$ where $\Omega_i=\bigcup_{i=1}^t\omega_{i,j}$ i.e. the $\omega_{i,j}$ is one of the $t$ spherical triangle components of the Voronoi cell i, which has one corner at node $\underline{x_i}$ and 2 corners that are adjacent voronoi vertexes.

If someone could provide the solution to 
$$\frac{1}{4}\int_0^{\alpha}\left(\cos^{-1}\left(Y\sin(\theta)+Z\cos(\theta)\right)\right)^3d\theta$$
it would solve the larger problem for me (this is a simpler and hopefully easier to integrate formulation of the same problem it replaced), everything in the last equation except $\theta$ is a constant

Comment: What does the superscript plus sign mean in $(Y-B\lambda)^+$? Or is that a typo?

Comment: This has been modified since I wrote it, but the typo could have been my doing: it should have been $(Y-B\lamda)^2+$, but I think I mat have come up with a better possibly more readily solvable framing of the problem... will need a little time to check

Comment: I've replaced the complicated integral with a much simpler one